# How to get rid of duplicate permalink in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I accidentally made two 'about' pages in wordpress 4.0. I erased one of them, and emptied the trash, so there was only one 'about' page. Now in the url, the permalink says 'about-2'. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the post and under the title you will see something like:

```
Permalink: http://example.com/about-2/ ‎Edit View Page Get Shortlink
```

Click the Edit button and remove the "-2" or remove all the text in that box and click "OK". Then update the page and the url should be "about"